# Как отключить автопрокрутку на сайте?

Tags: html, прокрутка

При переходе по ссылке site/#service возникает авто прокрутка сайта в зависимость от высоты расположения ссылки, если же site/#=service то прокрутки нет.

Вопрос, можно ли при нажатии на ссылку site/#service как то отключать авто прокрутку?

Answer (score 1):

В html такие ссылки называются [*якорями*](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya).
В javascript часть ссылки после знака решетки `#` называется *hash* и доступно через свойство `hash`

Для "отключения" прокрутки просто добавьте данный код на страницу:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, 1);
}
```